# What is wrong here? Getting amazon users email in alexa

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to develop an alexa skill and I would like to get the user's email and then compare it to those of a database. I found many examples on the web but they are all written in SDK v1 which is no longer supported.

following instructions and after reading the documentation I wrote this piece of code only that it doesn't work either on AWS or in the spoken test on alexa developer. What am I doing wrong?

```
var accessToken = this.event.context.System.apiAccessToken;

Bearer < ACCESS_TOKEN > 

Host: api.amazonalexa.it
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer MQEWY...6fnLok
GET https://api.amazonalexa.com/v2/accounts/~current/settings/Profile.email;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This repo has example code on using customer profile:  [GitHub: alexa-cookbook](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-cookbook/tree/master/feature-demos/skill-demo-customer-profile)

Search for the line:

```
const email = await client.getProfileEmail();
```

Comment: hello dear, it is in a old version and the comand "canhandle" return problems. I cant+'t find an example where has been used other comand

Comment: @Dany0596 As far as I can tell that repo is using v2, the latest version. Did you check this specific file? https://github.com/alexa/alexa-cookbook/blob/master/feature-demos/skill-demo-customer-profile/lambda/node/index.js